# Load a script within a function

Tags: jquery, load

I am trying to load a script within a function that depends on a variable of that function. Basically, the code is like this

```
head.js("somescript.js", function() {

   var dependentVar = //stuff;

    //insert script here which depends on dependentVar
});
```

Is this possible or anyone know how I can do this ? I need to do this because `dependentVar` contains C# code ?

Comment: $(document).load('script.js'), function(){ });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a design flaw. Instead of loading the code on the fly, can you encapsulate it in a function and pass `dependentVar` as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
$.getScript("somescript.js", function() {

   var dependentVar = //stuff;

    //insert script here which depends on dependentVar
    if(dependentVar) {
        $.getScript("somescript2.js", function() {

        });    
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure this works because just tried it and can't seem to get it working ?

Comment: so dependentVar = <%: someC#Var %>?  I am not sure how dependentVar is populated.